# Optimizing Python reading large files with eval

Tags: python, file, optimization, eval

I am writing a Python script (using Python 3.2) that at some point needs to through a file of around 800.000 lines for each key in a dictionary. The number of keys is around 150.000. The lines in the file are dictionaries of the following format:

```
{'url': 'http://address.com/document/42/1998', 'referrer': 'http://address.com/search?&q=query1', 'session': '1', 'rank': 2, 'time': 1338447254}
{'url': 'http://address.com/document/55/17', 'referrer': 'http://address.com/search&q=query2', 'session': '1', 'rank': 2, 'time': 13384462462}
```

For each line in this file I need do some computations and store the result. To be able to read the dictionary and work on it I use eval. This will result in 120.000.000.000 calls to eval, which takes a long time. I am therefore looking for a way to optimize this.

You're welcome to come with all possible suggestions for optimizations. Every bit may have an impact, but I'm mainly interested in eval and the way I read the file. Atm. I am thinking that some other method that eval may perform faster, but I can't make JSON read the format and using split has not turned out well yet.
Also the way I read from the file might be optimized. I have tried the method in the following code, along with "with" (was much slower, but consumed less memory). I also tried reading the file in memory using map:

```
f_chunk = map(eval, codecs.open(chunk_file, "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines())
```

But this does not really work either.

Anyway, the following part of the script is the heavy one. It is run in multiple processes:

```
def mine(id, tmp_sessions, chunk_file, work_q, result_q, init_qsize):
    #f_chunk = map(eval, codecs.open(chunk_file, "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines())
    f_chunk = codecs.open(chunk_file, "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines()

    while True:
        try:

            k = work_q.get()
            if k == 'STOP':

                work_q.task_done()
                break # reached end of queue

        except Queue.Empty:
            break

        #with codecs.open(chunk_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f_chunk:
        for line in f_chunk:
            #try:
            jlog_nest = dict()
            jlog_nest = eval(line)

            #jlog_nest = json.loads(line)
            #jlog_nest = line
            #jlog_nest = defaultdict(line)


            if jlog_nest["session"] == k: # If session is the same
                query_nest = prepare_test_cases_lib.extract_query(jlog_nest["referrer"])

                for q in tmp_sessions[k]:

                    if q[0] == query_nest:
                        url = jlog_nest["url"]
                        rank = jlog_nest["rank"]
                        doc_id = prepare_test_cases_lib.extract_document_id(url)

                        # Increase number of hits on that document, and save its rank
                        if doc_id in q[1]:
                            q[1][doc_id][0] += 1
                            q[1][doc_id][1].append(rank)
                        else:
                            q[1][doc_id] = [1, [rank]]
            #except:
            #    print ("error",k)

        result_q.put((k, tmp_sessions[k]))
        work_q.task_done()
```

If it helps understanding what happening tmp_session may look like this before the above code is run:

```
tmp_sessions: {'39': [['q7', {}], ['q2', {}]], '40': [['q2', {}]]}
```

And after:

```
tmp_sessions: {'39': [['q7', {}], ['q2', {'133378': [1, [2]]}]], '40': [['q2', {'133378': [1, [2]]}]]}
```

On a subset of the real data, with 562 keys and 2232 lines in the file I ran pstats, sorted descending by time (this is just the top):

```
1284892 function calls in 76.810 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     8    0.000    0.000   77.985    9.748 {built-in method exec}
     8    1.607    0.201   77.978    9.747 prepare_hard_test_cases.py:29(mine)
1254384   75.051    0.000   76.220    0.000 {built-in method eval}
   562    0.008    0.000    0.050    0.000 queues.py:99(put)
     8    0.000    0.000    0.029    0.004 codecs.py:685(readlines)
```

From this it seems that it is indeed eval taking up the time.

**Edit:** As suggested I tried with literal_eval. I actually found this trying to find a solution, but thought it would be the same as eval. I just ran it. It does produce the same result, but the run time is really bad:

```
 50205868 function calls (37662028 primitive calls) in 121.494 seconds

 Ordered by: cumulative time

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      8    0.001    0.000  121.494   15.187 {built-in method exec}
      8    0.008    0.001  121.493   15.187 <string>:1(<module>)
      8    4.935    0.617  121.485   15.186 prepare_hard_test_cases.py:29(mine)
1254384    5.088    0.000  116.425    0.000 ast.py:39(literal_eval)
1254384    1.098    0.000   71.432    0.000 ast.py:31(parse)
1254384   70.333    0.000   70.333    0.000 {built-in method compile}
13798224/1254384   22.996    0.000   39.336    0.000 ast.py:51(_convert)
7526304    8.539    0.000   23.042    0.000 ast.py:63(<genexpr>)
25087680    8.371    0.000    8.371    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
    8    0.001    0.000    0.047    0.006 codecs.py:685(readlines)
```

**Edit 2:** I have now tried two new approaches. The first one is by extracting key and values manually from each line, constructing a dictionary to work on. This works a little faster on my test set:

```
51460252 function calls in 45.207 seconds

 Ordered by: cumulative time

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      8    0.001    0.000   45.207    5.651 {built-in method exec}
      8    0.003    0.000   45.207    5.651 <string>:1(<module>)
      8    1.701    0.213   45.203    5.650 prepare_hard_test_cases.py:68(mine)
1254384    5.725    0.000   43.391    0.000 prepare_hard_test_cases.py:36(extractDict)
6271920   23.433    0.000   37.665    0.000 prepare_hard_test_cases.py:20(extractKeyValue)
18819074   11.308    0.000   11.308    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
25092651    2.927    0.000    2.927    0.000 {built-in method len}
```

This is good news, but even better is my second approach using pickle. Now I get:

```
30091 function calls in 5.285 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     8    0.000    0.000    5.285    0.661 {built-in method exec}
     8    0.003    0.000    5.285    0.661 <string>:1(<module>)
     8    0.173    0.022    5.281    0.660 prepare_hard_test_cases.py:68(mine)
   570    0.001    0.000    5.057    0.009 queues.py:113(get)
  2281    3.925    0.002    3.925    0.002 {method 'acquire' of '_multiprocessing.SemLock' objects}
   570    1.133    0.002    1.133    0.002 {method 'recv' of '_multiprocessing.PipeConnection' objects}
     8    0.029    0.004    0.029    0.004 {built-in method load}
```

When I get the time I will attempt to apply this approach to the full set.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
Casper

Comment: You should never need to use `eval()`.

Comment: Why does the `json` module fail?

Comment: @Lattyware presumably because `'` is not a valid string delimiter - `import json; json.loads("{'key': 'value'}")`

Comment: @Lattyware I am not sure. Might be as Jon mentions. It gives the following error: ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

Comment: @Casper if the data is guaranteed safe - it almost looks like it should be in a document orientated database instead of text files - that's if you have control over the data - then it's a MapReduce to do what you want - do you think that's a possibility?

Comment: @JonClements Ah, I thought it was the other way around. Yes, it's not valid JSON then, so `json` is out.

Comment: @JonClements Do you mean something like pickle? That is indeed a possibility, but will this perform faster? I am using pickle in a different part of the project. I have not tested it much, but it seemed really slow when saving and loading pickle files. I would have to rewrite some code, but if you think it would be worth it, I might have a look at it.

Comment: Also, if you have control over the data, have you considered making the structure a list of dicts and using a single call to `literal_eval()` or making it valid JSON (again, as a single list of objects) and parsing it with the `json` module? There might be a lot of overhead to the function.

Comment: @Lattyware I have updated my post. As you can see pickle did work really fast on the test set. I am looking forward to test it on the full set.

Answer (score 3):

You should give [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) a try, it's designed for the job, and will probably be faster.

`eval()` is slow, unsafe, and generally a bad idea. If you think you need it, take a look around, I assure you that you don't 99.99% of the time.

As another note:

```
f_chunk = codecs.open(chunk_file, "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines()
...
```

Should really be:

```
with open(chunk_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f_chunk:
    ...
```

Files are iterators, so using `readlines()` just makes your program less memory efficient. Using `with` ensures your file is closed properly once you are done (as you are in 3.x you can just use `open()` instead of `codecs.open()` as it has been updated to support the extra features of the latter).

Other than that, as far as I can see, each line of your data should be valid JSON, so the `json` module should work too.

Comment: I would tend to agree- but if `eval` does turn out needed - what prize does your guarantee cover ;) (darn - then you put in that cavaet!) :)

Comment: @JonClements I edited, as I knew someone would point it out - there are indeed rare cases where it could make sense - something where the user needs to be able to type in Python code and have it execute, for example - but that's insanely rare.

Comment: I have used `exec` in the past to generate a facade function with a signature matching the wrapped function, because the framework introspects these functions to marshall data into it's parameters.. It's one of those rare cases. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters `functools.wraps()`?

Comment: @Lattyware: Nope, that doesn't copy the function *signature*; the positional and keyword parameters.

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting case.

Comment: @Lattyware: It's part of the Zope [AccessControl package](https://github.com/zopefoundation/AccessControl/blob/master/src/AccessControl/requestmethod.py).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with literal_eval. It turned out to be slower in my case. I've updated the post with the pstat output. Also I tried with with, but it runs much slower this way.

Comment: @Casper I'm surprised by that. While there is hopefully a better solution to your problem, even being slower, I would always use `ast.literal_eval()` over `eval()` - `eval()` just has too many associated problems.

Comment: @Lattyware I indeed understand the problem with eval. Fortunately the files being read should be rather safe, so I do not see this as a problem in my case :) Regarding the use of with open wouldn't this have to read from the hard drive each time? The script is run on servers with plenty memory, so readlines would only make it run faster. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Casper I didn't see that you were looping to do this, in that case, reading the lines into memory may well make sense. Using `with` and `open()` are still good ideas, however.